# Cannot load my ui-calendar module

Tags: angularjs, ui-calendar

When i try to load my ui-calendar in my angular.module i am getting Uncaught Error: Injector error. How will i include my ui-calendar. I am using npm install.

This is my error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
at angular.js:38
at angular.js:4408
at n (angular.js:336)
at g (angular.js:4369)
at eb (angular.js:4294)
at d (angular.js:1655)
at yc (angular.js:1676)
at Zd (angular.js:1570)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:28683)
at j (jquery.js:3148)
```

This is my module were i am including ui-calendar:

```
var ebsapp = angular.module("ebs", ['ui.bootstrap', 'angular.filter', 'toastr', 'ui.calendar']);
```

Or is there any other script tags that needed to be included. if so please give me the script tags.

My injector error got resolved. I want to get a full calendar view.

I am using this div code:

```
<div ui-calendar ng-model="eventSources"></div>
```

How to get a simple calendar view??

Is these are the scripts i need to load ??

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
```

I tried to implement form https://jsfiddle.net/yy1rud17/326/ website where in i got the following out;

[image]

Whether i need to initialise my calendar??

Comment: show your scripts and their order

Comment: No i dont have script tags. can u send what are those script tags??

Comment: [`ui-calendar` usage](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar#usage) - adding a `angular-ui-calendar` script for a dependancy injection of the module

Comment: I tried all these, the thing they have given example with bower and not with npm. I am not using bower and it doesn't work. You have any other option ??

Comment: you can always add a [CDN manually](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-ui-calendar) if installation with npm is too complicated

Comment: Hy thanks my injector module error is solved with the CDN manually..!! But i am not able to view my calendar.

Comment: check the usage, you might need scripts for `fullcalendar.js`, `moment.js`, etc.

Comment: Please check my edits above for the fullcalendar.js scripts

Comment: Add this URL also to your scripts: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-calendar/1.0.0/calendar.min.js

Comment: Here you can find a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eddiriarte/yy1rud17/

Comment: Please check my edits after implementing code from  jsfiddle.net/eddiriarte/yy1rud17 website

Comment: I am getting fullcalendar is not a function error.